# Access is denied error with pregenerated .pyc or .pyo files

Tags: python, wxpython

I am getting an *Access is denied error* while I am trying to run the .pyo file by double click or from the command prompt.

Lets say I have abc.py (keeping main method entry point) which imports files xyz.py and imports wx etc.

I generate the .pyo file. But once I try to run abc.pyo I get the *access is denied* error.

I am not getting why this happening? Any help will really appreciated.

(I am using windows xp as os).
I am making .pyo from .py as following.

1. I am having a .bat file CompileAllToPyo.bat which have 
   python -O Compileall.py
2. The  Compileall.py keep the follwoing things

import os
import compileall
os.popen3(cmdLine, 'b')
compileall.compile_dir('.', force=1)

This is all the info 
Thanks

Comment: What platform are you on?  Also, what happens when you try to run abc.py instead of the .pyo file?

Comment: More details would be useful. *How* did you generate the `.pyo` file? As which user? What user account are you then trying to use it under? Does the issue still happen if the original `.py` files are not present? Have you checked which privileges (both read and write) the relevant user account has on the files? Etc.

Comment: To those answering, "access denied" implies this is a Windows box.  If that's so, Linux-specific solutions may not be helpful.

Comment: Hi Peter i am using windows xp os.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the system that your `hw.pyo` file is "executable", for example (in Linux, MacOSX, or any other Unix-y system) by executing the command `chmod +w hw.pyo` at the terminal shell prompt.  Consider, for example, the following short and simple shell session:

```
$ cat >hw.py
print('hello world')
$ python2.5 -O -c'import hw'
hello world
$ ./hw.pyo
bash: ./hw.pyo: Permission denied
$ chmod +x hw.pyo
$ ./hw.pyo
hello world
$
```

By default, `.pyo` (and `.pyc`) files are not marked as executable because they're mostly meant to be imported, not directly executed (indeed, note that we're explicitly using a Python `import` statement to **create** the `.pyo` file!); however, as this example shows, it's quite easy to make one of them "executable as the main script".  BTW, observe also:

```
$ cat >hw.py
print('hello world from ' + __name__)
$ python2.5 -O -c'import hw'
hello world from hw
$ chmod +x hw.pyo
$ ./hw.pyo
hello world from __main__
$
```

The `__name__` is what tells the module whether it's being `import`ed (so the first "hello world" says "from `hw`") or run as the main script (so the second one says "from `__main__`").  That's the reason modules that are designed to be used both ways normally end with `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` or the like, where `main` is a function that, this way, gets called iff the module's running as the main script (it's always best to have all substantial code execute in a function, not at a module's top level).

Answer (score 1):

You don't "run" a .pyo file, as it's not an executable. You can give it to the python interpreter in lieu of the .py file, but in general, you should use a .py file as your entry point, so that the .pyc or .pyo file can be recreated when necessary.

```
$ python imported.pyo
Success!
$ ./imported.pyo
bash: ./imported.pyo: Permission denied
```

Comment: @JimB, actually, on Windows a .pyo file (as with a .pyc or a .py) effectively appears executable (to a rookie) because there's an association between the file extension and the Python interpreter.  When you double-click the icon for the file you invoke the interpreter on it, much as the hash-bang line does on a posix-y system.  And I suspect "access denied" means he's on a Windows box, but of course we hardly know anything useful from the question, so who knows...

Comment: Ahh! I didn't even think that he meant "run" the pyo file in that way.

Comment: @Peter - Thanks, I didn't know that Windows would do that (I've been clean going on 8 years ;).

Comment: My meaning of running .pyo is double click or by command prompt of that pyo file.